# Can I use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy workers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

By workers I mean a python script that runs some task in an infinite loop. This script should be deployed to a separate EC2 instance and run forever (perhaps using supervisor).

I'm successfully using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy the web app with `git aws.push` and that works fine. However, the set-up for a worker needs to be a little different, because
the workers don't need a web server or an elastic IP. They are also started with a different command.

From what I've read I think what I want is pretty similar to Heroku's worker dynos vs web dynos, but I don't have any experience with Heroku either, so I could be wrong.
So is this possible with Elastic Beanstalk? Or should I be using something completely different for deployment?

By the way I'm using linux and the Elastic Beanstalk's CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Elastic Beanstalk has the same concept as Heroku's worker dynos and web dynos (Although I don't think these relate to your case where you are trying to run your custom worker process)

As it stands you can run your workers somewhere else. (EC2 instance, your own cloudserver, some very custom made SAS, etc)

Sidekiq/rescue (in the ruby world) is something equivalent to running workers independently. You can try this approach described in this [blog](http://blog.noizeramp.com/2013/04/21/using-sidekiq-with-elastic-beanstalk/) and apply to your specific worker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you think Heroku's worker dynos are different from what I want? As far as I understand they are like an ec2 instance that runs some custom command.

Comment: I don't like the approach in the blog post much, because I'd rather be able to add worker/web instances independently. But anyway, if elastic beanstalk doesn't support this, I'll just deploy workers using something else.

Comment: I believe adding more dynos means just adding more processing power to your application, but it doesn't provide granular control of how many workers are running inside the application. It's more like a high level of processing power. But I see what you are saying, in your case I guess you can deploy a second heroku application that represent your workers (the primary application being your web service that users the workers). This way if you need more worker "power" you can just increase the dynos.

Comment: I think this has changed. See Worker Environments http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Answer (score 9):

The ability to deploy background processes (workers) on ElasticBeanstalk was actually just introduced on December 11th.

Take a look at the announcement:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/12/background-task-handling-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html

and the docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: How does it compares to create a worker job in Heroku versus creating one in a Worker environment in Beanstalk?